# Adding ForeignKey to UserProfile giving foreign key constraint fails

Tags: django

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, and believe me, I really looked everywhere on Stack Overflow.

In my UserProfile, I have a ForeignKey reference to another model (called "Company"), and upon registration, I create a new Company and point my UserProfile ForeignKey to that Company.

models.py is as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '')
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, default = 0, null = True)

class Company(models.Model):
  """A company profile."""
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

I use a Form to do the signing up. Here's the form:

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
  name = forms.CharField(label = "Name")
  company = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
  email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("name", "company", "email", "password")

  def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(SignupForm, self).save(commit=False)
    name = self.cleaned_data["name"].split()
    if len(name) == 1:
      # User did not enter a last name.
      user.first_name = name
    else:  
      user.first_name, user.last_name = name
    user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
    user.username = user.email
    if commit:
      user.save()

    return user
```

and here's the signup view:

```
def signup(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      # Check if email has already been used for an account.
      email = request.POST['email']
      existing_account = User.objects.filter(email = email)
      if existing_account:
        form = SignupForm()
        return render_to_response('registration/signup.html',
          { 'form': form,
            'error': 'duplicate_email',
          })

      # Otherwise, save the form and create a new user.
      new_user = form.save()

      company = Company(name=request.POST['company'])
      company.save()

      user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
      user_profile.company = company
      user_profile.save()

      new_user = authenticate(
        username = email,
        password = request.POST['password']
      )
      # Log the user in automatically.
      login(request, new_user)

      # Redirect user to Thank You page.
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
  else:
    form = SignupForm()

  return render_to_response('registration/signup.html', {
    'form': form,
  })
```

The error I am getting is telling me that company_id cannot be null. I clearly add  a new Company. Please let me know what you think might be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the error. I want to know the line

Comment: Thanks for the response. The lines that are referenced in the error are:       new_user = form.save() and  user.save(). The error is (1048, "Column 'company_id' cannot be null")

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact error today, with no reason, except that it was caused by SQLite. With SQLite, the id field of one table went from INTEGER PRIMARY KEY to INTEGER. If you're using SQLite, try deleting the offending table and recreate it with a syncdb.

What is the value of

```
user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
```

?

Comment: I am using MySQL, and the id field is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Also, the value of that I would presume is null, since I don't see anything in my user_profile table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this feels too hackish for your tastes but perhaps you could create/save the Company object and pass it in to your SignupForm.save() method as a positional/keyword argument.

The issue you'd get there is that you'd be expecting a CharField and you'd be passing in a company object.  So you'd probably want to give company.pk to the company field in your form.